# PUT Fetch en React Native no actualiza back

Tags: reactjs, hook, native

estoy queriendo crear un componente para actualizar datos de usuario, cuestion que los datos que tengo controlados con **react hook form** los hace bien pero tengo un checkbox que es un componente propio que no me envia los datos al back, no se que estoy haciendo mal, en el onsubmit tengo lo siguiente :

```
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    const gender = updatedGender

    const data = {
      ...values,
      gender
    };
    console.log(data)
    await connect({ url: URL.UPDATE_PROFILE, data });
    navigation.goBack(null);
  };
```

updateGender es un booleano y desde el back se me estan actualizando todos los datos menos gender, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: que hace tu funcion updatedGender? has intentando hacer? `!gender` esto niega el valor del genero si es true pasa a falso si es falso cambia true

Comment: updatedGender es un useState, viene de un checkbox que devuelve true o false dependiendo si el genero es masculino o femenino, hasta ahí llega bien ese true o false, pero no lo agrega al back, no se si tengo que agregarle el gender de otra manera al values (algo así como concatenarlo)